# Not able to access running server on docker in uvicorn

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I have already ran a uvicorn server in docker, its running fine too but i am not able to see it

```
FROM python
RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn mongoengine
EXPOSE 8002
COPY ./app /app
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/app"
VOLUME /app
RUN cd app
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "8002"]
```

This ran successfully and i am seeing this success logs as well

```
D:\***\****\****>docker logs a1b
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8002 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

On visiting

- http://127.0.0.1:8002/

its saying
**This page isn’t working**

How should i access this then..

On `docker ps -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                                 NAMES
832bf82a0fb1        edmaskbackend6      "uvicorn main:app ..."   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds                   127.0.0.1:32772->8002/tcp             infallible_cray
```

Comment: `--host 127.0.0.1` makes the process inaccessible from outside its container.  Use `--host 0.0.0.0` instead.

Comment: i actually ran it like `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1::8002 edmaskbackend6` which means my access point now is  `127.0.0.1:8002`

Comment: @David Maze you are the super man of mine, thank you so much!