# Custom Docker image not publishing port properly

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a Dockerfile with `EXPOSE 8000` in it.  The Docker Compose file that runs it has:

```
services:
    api:
        image: <local image>
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

When I exec into the container, the api is running and I can `curl` it.  However, I cannot reach it from the host.

Comment: What's running inside the container?  Is it listening only on the 127.0.0.1 container-private localhost address?  See for example [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)

Comment: It's listening on `localhost:8000` yeah.  Do I need to do some kind of port forwarding?  I thought that's what `EXPOSE` did?

Comment: @DavidMaze it's a Python HTTP server

Comment: `EXPOSE` only adds metadata to the image to indicate what ports the container "should" be listening on when running, but it's just that (metadata). It's still needed for the container's process to be listening on the port.

If the process is listening on localhost/127.0.0.1, it can only be accessed from within the container itself. To make it accessible from outside the container, use `0.0.0.0`. The port needs to be mapped (`-p 8000:8000` in your case) to make it publicly accessible from outside the Docker Host

Comment: @thaJeztah Yes that's what the `ports` field is doing in the docker-compose file.  The container is like this: `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp  `

Comment: And does your Python app listen on port `8000`? It may listen on `80`.

Comment: @Saeed it does, yeah.  When I run it on the host machine directly, navigating to `http://localhost:8000` successfully opens the app.

Comment: It's using FastAPI.  Maybe there's something here? ```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:45506 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK```. It listens on 8000 but maybe Docker has an issue with that randomly generated port?

Comment: "Running on 127.0.0.1:..." means it won't be accessible from outside the container.  It looks like it supports a `--host 0.0.0.0` to make it accessible from everywhere ([Not able to access running server on docker in uvicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299144/not-able-to-access-running-server-on-docker-in-uvicorn)).

Comment: @DavidMaze that was it -- thanks!